# how to avoid data repetition while insert in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

i have data like company has branch in multiple city and each city has company three different offices office1, office2 and office3

Data is like below,

- company1

  - city1

    - Address of office 1, Address of office 2, Address of office 3
  - city2

    - Address of office 1, Address of office 2, Address of office 3
  - city3

    - Address of office 1, Address of office 2, Address of office 3
- company2

  - city1

    - Address of office 1, Address of office 2, Address of office 3
  - city2

    - Address of office 1, Address of office 2, Address of office 3
  - city3

    - Address of office 1, Address of office 2, Address of office 3

So i need to validate that once company1 address store for city1 then it should not be stored again database, as well if address of office 1 stored for city1 then it will not be stored again. I used laravel 5.3 version.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include some codes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look into documentation?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#other-creation-methods
You can try to use firstOrCreate/ firstOrNew methods.

Comment: I have hierarchy like company -> city -> office address, and i need to check it for City and Office address, name of company,city and office address all are stored in single table

Comment: Why must to hierarchy strategy. In my opinion u can save this in one table like that: company_id, city_id, office_id, address

Comment: @Ts8060 can you please explain me in brief.